# how can show 3 row in 1 row in sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

i have 1 question in sql

how can i show 3 row in row ?

here is my sql code

```
SELECT jobcard.code AS code1,jobcard.name AS name1,nvl(masterpm.id,0)toal 
FROM jobcard 
  LEFT JOIN masterpm ON jobcard.id = masterpm.jobcard_id 
                    and masterpm.id in (select masterpm_id from cbmmasterpm)
```

and image from select result 
[image]

now how i can show 3 toal row in 1 row and code ,name dont get repeat i really need that

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tagas.

Comment: @GordonLinoff thanks :)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` all the `TOAL` values if you are using MySQL, e.g.:

```
SELECT jobcard.code AS code1,jobcard.name AS name1, GROUP_CONCAT(NVL(masterpm.id,0)) AS toal 
FROM jobcard LEFT JOIN masterpm ON jobcard.id = masterpm.jobcard_id AND masterpm.id in (SELECT masterpm_id FROM cbmmasterpm)
GROUP BY code1, name1;
```

[Here's](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) MySQL documentation for `GROUP_CONCAT`.

**update**

As you are using Oracle, you can use `listagg` function to achieve the same functionality, e.g.:

```
SELECT jobcard.code AS code1, jobcard.name AS name1,
LISTAGG(NVL(masterpm.id,0), ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY masterpm.id) "TOAL"
FROM jobcard LEFT JOIN masterpm ON jobcard.id = masterpm.jobcard_id AND masterpm.id in (SELECT masterpm_id FROM cbmmasterpm)
GROUP BY code1, name1;
```

[Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) the documentation.

Comment: ty but i using oracle

Comment: which version of oracle?

Comment: oracle 11.0.2 or 11g